# How to convert DateTime to timestamp in android?

Tags: android, timestamp-with-timezone

How to convert DateTime to timestamp in android?

```
String str_offerbegin = start_time;

SimpleDateFormat df_offerbegin = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mmaa");

df_offerbegin.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

but not getting exact time and date?

Comment: I added a bunch of links of results when I altered the google search, feel free to check them out

Comment: post a sample output what you want to achieve and current output in your question.

Comment: No problem, if it was correct, mark as answer, otherwise post your code and mark that

Comment: Input: start_time = Apr 09, 2014 12:22PM... I m getting timestamp (1396983120) when converting this date... but it was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This is literally the first thing that popped up when I googled your question. Try to do some effort before asking a question

[DateTime to Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682891/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-in-java)

Maybe these can help you:

[convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670355/convert-date-time-for-given-timezone-java)
[convert-date-to-different-timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197956/convert-date-to-different-timezone)

**Example**

```
DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss Z");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
  System.out.println(formatter.format(instance2.getTime()))
```

Comment: Yeah... already i did timestamp conversion but i want to convert date and time with localtimezone (GMT+5.30)

Comment: you want to get your locatimezone ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(str_offerbegin);
```

Comment: I tried this one... String str_offerbegin = start_time;
     SimpleDateFormat df_offerbegin = new SimpleDateFormat(
     "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mmaa");
     df_offerbegin.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     Date date_offerbegin = df_offerbegin.parse(str_offerbegin);
     long epoch_offerbegin = (date_offerbegin.getTime())/1000;

Comment: Using above code I was unable to get the current local time... Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you simple **set default timezone** in **UTC** by following way,

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));   // for (GMT+5.30)
```

Above line base on your need any one you add before following code, Now you can **access date** with **default timezone**.

```
String str_offerbegin = start_time;
SimpleDateFormat df_offerbegin = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mmaa");
df_offerbegin.parse(str_offerbegin);
```

---

Another best helpfull [**JodaTime**](http://www.joda.org/) Class. Joda Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes.
Using Joda Time,

```
String str_offerbegin = start_time;
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");

DateTime datetime = new DateTime(str_offerbegin,timeZone);
String resultdate = datetime.toString();   // Result in String

DateTime dateutc = datetime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Input: start_time = Apr 09, 2014  12:22PM... I m getting timestamp (1396983120) when converting this date... but it was wrong...

Comment: its not working any more . It always return wrong timestamp